# Effect of activeIndex attribute when dynamic="true" in a p:tabView

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

Can we set activeIndex attribute in p:tabView to non zero if we set dynamic attribute to true?

Comment: Did you try it and it didn't work?

Comment: @XtremeBiker Yes we could do that. When I put activeIndex="1" with dynamic="true" it was showing first tab with a blank page. I redeployed my app several times but still was not working. But after a long time it started working. I didn't see any errors in the server console and any script errors in the browser. So at last I posted a question here. Anyway Thanks for the response.

Comment: @kolossus Yes i have tried but was not working. And after several builds things are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. The dynamic attribute enables lazy loading of inactive tabs, while activeIndex is the property of the active tab.

Comment: Yeah actually we can and I don't why it was not working in my machine. Now every thing is working fine. Hence accepted your answer.